# Form Authentication / Login a site using Scrapy

Tags: python, http, web-scraping, scrapy

I am a beginner with Scrapy. I am trying to login a site for me to be able to do scraping. But I am stuck.
Below is the code in my spider

**Spider:**

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.log import log

class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "login"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    start_urls = [
    "http://example.com/login"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        form = hxs.select("//form[@id = 'login']/text()").extract()

        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            #loginid = "name" attribute of the username field
            response,
            formdata={'loginid': 'username', 'password': 'password'}, 
            callback=self.after_login
        )

    def after_login(self, response):
        if "authentication failed" in response.body:
            return
    else: 
        print "I am in"
```

**Log:**

```
[tutorial]$ scrapy crawl login
/home/tutorial/tutorial/spiders/login.py:5: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: tutorial.spiders.login.LoginSpider inherits from deprecated class scrapy.spider.BaseSpider, please inherit from scrapy.spider.Spider. (warning only on first subclass, there may be others)
  class LoginSpider(BaseSpider):
2015-05-07 06:05:02-0700 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.24.4 started (bot: tutorial)
2015-05-07 06:05:02-0700 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2015-05-07 06:05:02-0700 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'tutorial.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['tutorial.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'tutorial'}
2015-05-07 06:05:02-0700 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: LogStats, TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
2015-05-07 06:05:02-0700 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2015-05-07 06:05:02-0700 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2015-05-07 06:05:02-0700 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: 
2015-05-07 06:05:02-0700 [login] INFO: Spider opened
2015-05-07 06:05:02-0700 [login] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2015-05-07 06:05:02-0700 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2015-05-07 06:05:02-0700 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 127.0.0.1:6080
2015-05-07 06:05:03-0700 [login] DEBUG: Crawled (401) <GET http://example.com/login> (referer: None)
2015-05-07 06:05:03-0700 [login] DEBUG: Ignoring response <401 http://example.com/login>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2015-05-07 06:05:03-0700 [login] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2015-05-07 06:05:03-0700 [login] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
    {'downloader/request_bytes': 238,
     'downloader/request_count': 1,
     'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
     'downloader/response_bytes': 33245,
     'downloader/response_count': 1,
     'downloader/response_status_count/401': 1,
     'finish_reason': 'finished',
     'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 7, 13, 5, 3, 309509),
     'log_count/DEBUG': 4,
     'log_count/INFO': 7,
     'response_received_count': 1,
     'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
     'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
     'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
     'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
     'start_time': datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 7, 13, 5, 2, 518131)}
2015-05-07 06:05:03-0700 [login] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

I am getting the following in the logs:

```
**2015-05-07 06:05:03-0700 [login] DEBUG: Crawled (401) <GET http://example.com/login> (referer: None)
2015-05-07 06:05:03-0700 [login] DEBUG: Ignoring response <401 http://example.com/login>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed**
```

I am not sure how to resolve this error and authenticate successfully. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

**Edit:** 
example.com mentioned in my code is an example URL
The page I am trying to authenticate has the below login form:

```
<div class="Login">
    <h4>Log in here</h4>
    <form id="login" action="/login.action" method="post">
    <ul>
        <li><label for="user_id">User Id :</label></li>
        <li><input type="text" name="loginid" maxlength="30" value="" class="login"></li>
        <li><label for="user_id">Password :</label></li>
        <li><input type="password" name="password" maxlength="30" class="login"></li>
        <li><input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btnSubmit"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Your form data might be not enough for that post reqeust or sometimes you may need some extra parameters too, so better post the exact start-url.

Comment: The URL cant be accessed publicly. What exact information are you looking for. I can get it. Below is the login form:

<div class="Login">
 <h4>Log in here</h4>
 <form id="login" action="/login.action" method="post">
 <ul>
  <li><label for="user_id">User Id :</label></li>
  <li><input type="text" name="loginid" maxlength="30" value="" class="login"></li>
  <li><label for="user_id">Password :</label></li>
  <li><input type="password" name="password" maxlength="30" class="login"></li>
  <li><input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btnSubmit"></li>
 </ul>
</div>

Answer (score 1):

OK, Apologies - my bad. The URL that I am trying to authenticate has a javascript pop asking for login info before actually giving a 401 and showing the login form in the web page. Hence my spider was not working. 
But having said that, is there a way, this javascript login form can be handled in Scrapy?

Comment: Javascript login can be handled with Selenium or similar tool. Search for tutorial on how to use Selenium with Scrapy.

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to authenticate on the page http://example.com/login that:

1. doesn't have any authentication form
2. responds with [404 response
   code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404), which means broken or dead link. Scrapy ignores such pages
   by default.

Try with real webpage that actually has an authentication form.

Comment: The example.com is, as it conveys, an example URL. The page I am trying to access indeed has a login form, below is the snippet of the form:

<div class="Login">
 <h4>Log in here</h4>
 <form id="login" action="/login.action" method="post">
 <ul>
  <li><label for="user_id">User Id :</label></li>
  <li><input type="text" name="loginid" maxlength="30" value="" class="login"></li>
  <li><label for="user_id">Password :</label></li>
  <li><input type="password" name="password" maxlength="30" class="login"></li>
  <li><input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btnSubmit"></li>
 </ul>
</div>